# insertAdjacentHtml in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

for some reason when using insertAdjacentHtml function in FF I am getting insertAdjacentHTMl is not a function error, is there an alternative to this in jQuery or some other alternative javascript function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jquery uses  various functions to achieve this :

Read about:
http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/
http://api.jquery.com/append/
http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/
http://api.jquery.com/prepend/
http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/
... and more

And more in jQuery Manipulation API documentation:
http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/

Answer (score 22):

It depends on how you're using it.

```
.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeBegin", ...) //$('...').before(...)
.insertAdjacentHTML("afterBegin", ...) //$('...').prepend(...)
.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeEnd", ...) //$('...').append(...)
.insertAdjacentHTML("afterEnd", ...) //$('...').after(...)
```

http://api.jquery.com/before/

http://api.jquery.com/after/

http://api.jquery.com/append/

http://api.jquery.com/prepend/

---

**Code Example**

```js
$('<p class="border">PrependTo</p>').prependTo($('.main'));
    $('.main').prepend('<p class="border">Prepend</p>');

    $('<p class="border">AppendTo</p>').appendTo($('.main'));
$('.main').append('<p class="border">Append</p>');


$('<p class="border">Insert After</p>').insertAfter('.main');

$('<p class="border">Insert Before</p>').insertBefore('.main');
```

```css
.border {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main border">
  <p>Main</p>
</div>
```

Comment: There's a critical mistake in the mapping. `afterBegin` and `afterEnd` are transposed. I've added a corrected version [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40431232/168874) (as my edit was rejected).

Answer (score 10):

To extend and correct [@Adam Terlson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/650094/adam-terlson)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6617914/168874) :

Here's the mapping of [`insertAdjacentHTML` `position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) values and the associated [jQuery DOM insertion functions](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-outside/).

## `beforebegin` / [`before`](http://api.jquery.com/before/)

```
document.getElementById('foo').insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin", "<hr>")
$('#foo').before("<hr>")
```

## `afterend` / [`after`](http://api.jquery.com/after/)

```
document.getElementById('foo').insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", "<hr>")
$('#foo').append("<hr>")
```

## `beforeend` / [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

```
document.getElementById('foo').insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<hr>")
$('#foo').append("<hr>")
```

## `afterbegin` / [`prepend`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)

```
document.getElementById('foo').insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", "<hr>")
$('#foo').prepend("<hr>")
```

The MDN page has a [good visualization of what these mean](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML#Visualization_of_position_names) that looks like this :

```
<!-- beforebegin / before -->
<p>
  <!-- afterbegin / prepend -->
  foo
  <!-- beforeend / append -->
</p>
<!-- afterend / after-->
```

The mistake in [@Adam Terlson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/650094/adam-terlson)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6617914/168874) was that `afterBegin` and `afterEnd` were transposed.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand right, you want to append at the end of a DOM element

you can doit with jquery appendTo

here is the documentation http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example on this.

```js
$('<p class="border">PrependTo</p>').prependTo($('.main'));
    $('.main').prepend('<p class="border">Prepend</p>');

    $('<p class="border">AppendTo</p>').appendTo($('.main'));
$('.main').append('<p class="border">Append</p>');


$('<p class="border">Insert After</p>').insertAfter('.main');

$('<p class="border">Insert Before</p>').insertBefore('.main');
```

```css
.border {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main border">
  <p>Main</p>
</div>
```