# Adding html before and after with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a button I would like to wrap with multiple html elements with classes. I have tried multiple approaches but it either does not work I get errors.

```
jQuery(".button--bubble").insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin','<div class="class-1"><div class="class-2"></div></div>');
jQuery(".button--bubble").insertAdjacentHTML('afterend','<div class="class-1"><div class="class-2"></div></div>');
```

Comment: This is a native javascript method - look at this instead https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6617829/insertadjacenthtml-in-jquery

Comment: You are not wrapping anything with this code, you are just placing it before or after your button

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pure javascript method to wrap content in a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6838104/pure-javascript-method-to-wrap-content-in-a-div)

Comment: Try like this : `jQuery('<div class="class-1"><div class="class-2"></div></div>').insertBefore('.button--bubble');jQuery('<div class="class-1"><div class="class-2"></div></div>').insertAfter('.button--bubble');`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".button--bubble").before('beforebegin','<div class="class-1"></div><div class="class-2"></div>');
$(".button--bubble").after('afterend','<div class="class-1"><div class="class-2"></div></div>');
```

Also you can use `.prepend` and `.append` they are similar but, the elements will be inside the targeted elements .